# Releasing packages on Play store

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

So, I have a fairly large app that I'd like to distribute via packages in the Play store.  I see this tactic used quite often.  I haven't seen much in the way of actually doing it. From what I've gathered so far the logic in code would work like this:

```
try {
  Start activity in package
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  Prompt user to play store by using the package name as the URL
}
```

Aside from that, I'm wondering what kind of setup is required for the packages.  They shouldn't be opened from a launcher (my app only).

What intent filters should the packages have applied to them if any?

Is it possible to set up the Manifest in such a way that I can make it unsearchable in Google Play but still be downloaded if linked directly to it?